# Upload a file in Classic ASP without another class completely custom

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, runtime-error

Yes I am using Classic ASP, not by choice I am supporting a Legacy application. Objective: I need to have a form page that submits to another .asp page that will upload the file and store it on the server in a certain directory such as "/uploads". I'm not real familiar with asp or asp.net so I am very new to this. I've created a test prototype:

Form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="process.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p>Filename: <input type="text" name="filename" size="50" /></p>
     <p><input type="file" name="file" /><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Processing page:

```
<%

Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set tfolder = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2)
tname = fs.GetTempName

'Declare variables
Dim fileSize
Dim filename
Dim file
Dim fileType
Dim p
Dim newPath

'Assign variables
fileSize       = Request.TotalBytes
fileName       = Request.form("filename")
file           = request.form("file")
fileType       = fs.GetExtensionName(file)
fileOldPath    = tfolder
newPath        = Server.MapPath("/uploads/")

fs.MoveFile fileOrigPath, newPath


set fs = nothing

%>
```

The problem is that everytime I try to upload or run the script I get this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0035'
File not found
/tbird/fileUpload/process.asp, line 25
```

Obviously I'm not mapping correctly to the file and I think the major reason I am getting stuck is that in the first parameter of the `MoveFile` method I am not mapping to the file correctly. Can anyone tell me how I should be referencing the file or if I am doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance I would really appreciate the help I've searched all over and everything I find related to classic asp and uploading files are classes that you can purchase and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Your code does not upload anything. In classic ASP it can't be done in one line, complicated code must be used since you have to read the raw binary data and parse it yourself. you can also use code I wrote some years back, it can be found [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-additional-features-94647.html) you need to take the file from the ZIP file and there is sample code.

Comment: I wondered if that may be the case, so essentially what you are saying is that I have to take the file and read it then write those contents to a file and save it somewhere? I'm so confused on this I'm a php developer so supporting a legacy application in asp has certainly been a learning curve

Comment: The browser is sending the file contents plus all form data as one single binary stream of data to the server, the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is responsible for that. The server then needs to parse that raw data back to file contents and form data, PHP and ASP.NET are smart enough to do that without extra code but classic ASP is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at a solution like [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm), it should help you. In classic ASP, you cannot directly access `Request.Form` when data is sent in *multipart/form-data*, so you have the choice of using a third party component like [ASPUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/) or a ASP class that does the work of parsing the request for you and exposing methods to save the file.

Answer (score -1):

When moving files you must also specify the file names.

Change:

```
fs.MoveFile fileOrigPath, newPath
```

To:

```
fs.MoveFile fileOrigPath & fileName, newPath & fileName
```

Assuming "fileName" is the correct variable for the file name and not "file" variable above.

Comment: That's the problem in php when you upload something your file gets placed somewhere with a temp name before being moved. I need to figure out a way to get the files base in order to properly move it. However from comments, answers and other articles what I am trying to do in the way I'm doing it just doesn't sound possible and I feel like I am missing a much bigger picture in how things are done in classic asp

Comment: The file gets placed in ASP where you write to place it, unless you upload into memory but from (my) memory there are not many COM's that can do this. 99% of the time you upload to a write enabled directory (usually outside of the wwwroot) and then move it from there inside of the wwwroot as moving files does not require write permissions as the account IIS is running or the autheticated user will have permissions to move files.

You just need to put the full path when moving files.